# How do I move static IP address from one ISP to another

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address

We have a linux server pointing to a static IP address from one major ISP.  We recently changed that ISP to a new ISP and I am wondering if there is a way we can move the static IP address to work through the new ISP.

Is it even possible to move static IP address from ISP to another?

Comment: Nope, this is a great benefit of Domain Names though :)

Comment: Yup this is what DNS is for.

Answer (score 28):

Unless the ISPs share netblocks (very unlikely), this is not a realistic outcome.

If you're looking to keep the static IP for DNS reasons, you should instead lower your TTLs and keep both ISPs (and by extension, IP addresses) until you can gracefully migrate.

Answer (score 22):

Unless you own the IP address block it's in, and it's in Provider Independent (PI) Space, then you might be able to switch transit providers, and announce your routes over your new BGP sessions with your new ISP, then it might be possible.

Given the lack of networking knowledge show in the OP's question, these assumptions seem unlikely.

Comment: Yeah, based on the "we have _a_ linux server" and wording around ISPs, "I jumped to the TTL + DNS, pay both bills" response.